# Не срабатывает задание из крона

Tags: linux, ftp, cron, freebsd, резервное-копирование

Добавил в крон задания для переноса бекапов на `ftp`. Каждую пятницу файлы должны бекапится на сервер. Однако через `cron` данный скрипт не отрабатывает. Если я вручную запущу через `sh` - то все работает нормально. Что не так?

```
50  0   *   *   2,4 root     /usr/local/is/bin/daily_backup.sh
50  1   *   *   5   root    /usr/local/bin/ftpBackup.sh
```

Содержимое файла **ftpBackup.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
ftp -in -u ftp://Login:Passwordftp@10.28.1.1/xxx/Thursday.files.tgz /usr/local/is/backup/Thursday.files.tgz
```

Comment: Попробуй по одному пробелу в настройках времени. И что такое `root`?

Comment: *Добавил в крон* — каким именно образом?

Comment: Окружение у крона своё. `ftp` программа где лежит может не знать он. Путь полный указать надо. Тоже к другим программам скриптов внутри.

Comment: @PinkTux, это если в теле crontab писать команды. Когда запускаешь скрипт с шебангом - все пути нормально подсовываются.

Comment: Можно попробовать еще добавить команду bash перед расположением скрипта.

Comment: @donRumata, шебанг тут никаким боком.

Comment: @PinkTux, значит меня глючит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Что не так?

Дело в том, что Вы запускаете эти скрипты из командной строки шелла, имеющего ВАШИ env-переменные, а cron запускает их из под своего. Соответственно, там будет другая домашняя директория, другие пути, другие права и всё такое прочее - посмотрите внимательно на Ваши скрипты!

У меня, к примеру, была проблема в том, что в скрипте я делал вход по SSH на другой комп по ранее созданному ключу и в командной строке всё работало. Но при запуске по крону, ssh уже не мог найти мой ключ и падал во время логина. Прописал полный путь к ключу - всё заработало.

Answer (score 1):

Во время выполнения задачи по крону, если возникают ошибки, то они должны (как правило) приходить администратору на почту. Если конечно у вас все настроено корректно в этом плане (имею в виду переадресацию почты для root).

Как вариант перенаправьте вывод в файл:

```
#!/bin/bash
ftp -in -u ftp://Login:Passwordftp@10.28.1.1/xxx/Thursday.files.tgz /usr/local/is/backup/Thursday.files.tgz > /var/log/ftp_cron 2>&1
```

и проверьте содержимое файла после предположительного запуска задачи.

Comment: Если на хосте стоит и настроен smtp, то да.

Comment: Такой файл даже не появляется в файловой системе

Comment: такое ощущение будто крон не работает толком

Comment: *  *  *  *  *   root  date > /tmp/test_cron

Comment: Проверьте задачу в кроне и посмотрите логи /var/log/ на предмет наличия информации о запуске задач.